# How to fix CoreGraphics dashed line changing when view is resized

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics

I have a subclass of an NSView that is drawing a series of dashed lines. When I resize the window that the view is in, the dashed lines change their patterns. How can I prevent the lines from changing their patterns during a window resize?

The lines are being drawn in the following function:

```
func drawLines(in context: CGContext) {
    for line in lines {
        context.move(to: line.start)
        context.addLine(to: line.end)
        context.setLineDash(phase: 0, lengths: [10, 10])
        context.strokePath()
    }
}
```

This function is called from draw(_:):

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    guard let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext else { return }

    drawLines(in: context)
}
```

When the window is resized, the line pattern changes - sometimes that dashed line looks completely solid:

[image: Image Example 1]
[image: Image Example 2]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my `lines` array contained lines going in both directions for each line. This meant that for each line, it was drawing a dashed line in both directions. These dashed lines were overlapping and would go in and out of phase when resizing, which lead to this behavior.